# FadeIn 1000 when add class by Click

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, click

I'm trying to `fadeIn 1000` when add class by Click function.

*I have tried this:* http://jsfiddle.net/rf7mudL5/

**HTML**

```
<span class="date-outer">Text will Red on fadeIn</span>

<button class="more-recent-button"></button>
```

**JS**

```
$(".more-recent-button").click(function(){
 $(".date-outer").fadeIn("1000").addClass("more-date-outer");
});
```

So how to opacity fadeIn when Class will add by click button?
Is possible this: when click button, content will fadeIn 1 time with out Opacity:0 to 1 or without css, means fadeIn content 1 time when click. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this if you need utilize opacity-change:

```
$(".more-recent-button").click(function () {
  if (!$(".date-outer").hasClass('more-date-outer')) {
    $(".date-outer").fadeTo('slow', 0, function () {
         $(this).addClass("more-date-outer").fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });
  }
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/rf7mudL5/8/

Comment: Great!, but how fadeIn 1 time when click button, because it's always fadeIn, how fadeIn 1 time, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

**CSS:**

```
transition-duration: 1s;
```

**EDIT:**
Opacity fadein: http://jsfiddle.net/rf7mudL5/9/

Comment: Sorry i trying to fadeIn opacity, any suggestion for opacity fadeIn

Comment: Is that what you need?

Comment: Is possible that, when click button, content will fadeIn 1 time with out Opacity:0 to 1, i means fadeIn content 1 time. any suggestion?

Comment: Using my code fadein runs only once, because once the button is clicked opacity grows from 0 to 1.. The second time it won't work.. Of course, If I understand you correctly..

Comment: Great, but question was for JS only, not css.

Answer (score 1):

`.fadeIn()` simply fades the element in if its invisible. to animate the color the easiest way in your case would be to change transition duration for your text:

```js
$(".more-recent-button").click(function() {
  $(".date-outer").fadeIn("1000").addClass("more-date-outer");
});
```

```css
.more-date-outer {
  color: red;
}
.more-recent-button {
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
.date-outer {
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="date-outer">Text will Red on fadeIn</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<button class="more-recent-button"></button>
```

**UPDATE:**

if you want to fade the text once on button click, you simply hide it first and then fade it in.

note:

- the duration should not be in quote marks.
- you need to check if the text has the new class yet, and fade it only if it still doesnt have it.

```js
$(".more-recent-button").click(function() {
  if (!$(".date-outer").hasClass("more-date-outer")) {
    $(".date-outer").hide();
    $(".date-outer").fadeIn(1000).addClass("more-date-outer");
  }
});
```

```css
.more-date-outer {
  color: red;
}
.more-recent-button {
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="date-outer">Text will Red on fadeIn</span>

<br/>
<br/>
<button class="more-recent-button"></button>
```

Comment: Is possible that, when click button, content will fadeIn 1 time with out Opacity:0 to 1, i means fadeIn content 1 time. any suggestion?

Comment: @Aabira Do you need something like [This](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/rf7mudL5/6/) ?

Comment: Thanks, but how fadeIn 1 time when click button, because it's always fadeIn, how fadeIn 1 time, any suggestion?